# Handle click in VueJS and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js

I'm new in Vue, and I'm really in doubt about something. Well, I'm in doubt about the way we handle click event in `Vue and jQuery`. For me, at this moment, jQuery seems to be more simple to achieve.

in jQuery we just do that:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="jquery-radio">
Radio 1 <input type="radio" name="radio" class="choose-radio" value="Radio1" checked>
<br>
Radio 2 <input type="radio" name="radio" class="choose-radio" value="Radio2">
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.choose-radio').click(function() {
    $('.choose-radio:checked').val() == 'Radio1' ? alert('Radio 1') :
    $('.choose-radio:checked').val() == 'Radio2' && alert('Radio 2 ');
});
```

So, my doubt is. How to achieve this, using Vue? I tried to do this, but as I said, jQuery seems to be more simple, because instead of add `@click="myMethod()"` i just do what I want, selecting the element (class) `$('.choose-radio);`

**HTML:**

```
<div class="jquery-radio">
Radio 1 <input type="radio" name="choose-radio-vue" class="choose-radio-vue" value="Radio1" checked @click="showRadio1()">
<br>
Radio 2 <input type="radio" name="choose-radio-vue" class="choose-radio-vue" value="Radio2" @click="showRadio2()">
```

**Vue**

```
var app = new Vue ({
    el: ".jquery-radio",
    methods: {
        showRadio1: function() {
            alert("Show 1");
        },
        showRadio2: function() {
            alert("Show 2");
        }
    }
   });
```

[Check Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LLn66nyo/2/)

These examples above, is basic. In my project, I'll show different sections based on the value previously chosen in radio. I'm realy confused in Vue.

Hope you guys can clarify this information for me!

Comment: Maybe it's a matter of taste, but your jQuery code is awefull ;-)

Comment: Yes, I know. But the goal of this question is to understand more about Vue, not for best practices, etc. Otherwise, I should be in Code Review with a completely diferent question, isn't it? @Gerfried

Comment: Can you add your exact use case what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the same handler and pass in the event object, which you can later use to retrieve the current element. Here's an working example:

```js
var app = new Vue ({
    el: ".jquery-radio",
    methods: {
        show: function(event) {
          var value = event.target.value
          
          console.log(value)
        }
    }
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<div class="jquery-radio">
   Radio 1 
   <input type="radio" name="choose-radio-vue" class="choose-radio-vue" value="Radio1" checked @click="show($event)">
<br>
   Radio 2 
   <input type="radio" name="choose-radio-vue" class="choose-radio-vue" value="Radio2" @click="show($event)">
</div>
```

PS: also, your jQuery approach is far from optimal, as it may yield errors if there are more elements that have the `.choose-radio` class. What you need is something like:

```
$('.choose-radio').click(function() {
    var value = $(this).val() // value of the selected object
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty different way of thinking. With Vue you want to change data and let Vue handle the DOM manipulation for you. I'd use `v-model` and toggle the visibility of sections based on that.

```js
new Vue({
  data: {
    section: 'Radio 1'
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <label><input name="section" type="radio" v-model="section" value="Radio 1"> One</label>
  <div v-if="section === 'Radio 1'">
    Radio One Is Selected!
  </div>

  <label><input name="section" type="radio" v-model="section" value="Radio 2"> Two</label>
  <div v-if="section === 'Radio 2'">
    Radio Two Is Selected!
  </div>

  <label><input name="section" type="radio" v-model="section" value="Radio 3"> Three</label>
  <div v-if="section === 'Radio 3'">
    Radio Three Is Selected!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you `-1` you should leave a comment and let me know why.

Comment: I gave +1 to reset this downvote, because answer is good and correct.It would be nice from downvoter to explain what is wrong :)